# Give an example of an operator that ${\cal D}(A)=X=l_1$, $Y=l_2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Give an example of an operator that ${\cal D}(A)=X=l_1$,  $Y=l_2$

operator $A: l_1 \to l_2$,

where
$l_1$ - set of numerical sequences $x=(x_1, x_2, ...)$, which satisfy $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|<\infty$, if $\rho(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k-y_k|$.

and

$l_2$ - set of numerical sequences $x=(x_1, x_2, ...)$, which satisfy $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|^2<\infty$, if $\rho(x,y)=(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k-y_k|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Can you clarify on what you have written means? Is $\mathcal{D}(A)$ the domain of $A$? Is $l_1$ the [$\ell^1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_countably_infinite_dimensions)-space? Also most people on this site prefer if you leave your on the thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Is the question: Give an example of an operator $A: \ell^1\to\ell^2$?

Comment: I added an explanation

Comment: $x\mapsto 0$. There are more interesting examples, such as the formal identity operator.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples. Any absolutely summable sequence is also square summable, so the idendity operator works

\begin{align}
A:\ell^1&\to\ell^2\\
(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty &\mapsto (x_k)_{k=1}^\infty.
\end{align}

You can also shift the index
\begin{align}
A:\ell^1&\to\ell^2\\
(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty &\mapsto (x_{k+1})_{k=1}^\infty.
\end{align}

I'm sure there are many more interesting examples.